# Drupal 7 webform submission to remote mysql database

Tags: database, drupal-7, drupal-webform

When a user fills out a webform on my Drupal 7 site, on submitting, I need the submission data to be sent over to another database.  I'm using hook_webform_submission_insert in a custom module, but I can only get the sid and nid to be inserted into the table.  I need my webform fields to be sent also; like first_name, last_name, email, etc.  But I get errors upon submitting.

```
<?php
function hook_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
  // Insert a record into a 3rd-party module table when a submission is added.
  db_insert('mymodule_table')
    ->fields(array(
      'nid' => $node->nid,
      'sid' => $submission->sid,
      'foo' => 'foo_data',
    ))
    ->execute();
}
?>
```

I've tried 'first_name' => 'first_name', but it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To get all the submitted data you'll have to go about this a slightly different way.  First add an additional submit handler to call a custom function in your module using form alter:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if($form_id == "YOUR_WEBFORM_ID") {
        $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_additional_insert';
    }
}
```

Then access the form data and process accordingly from your custom function.

```
function MYMODULE_additional_insert($form, &$form_state) {

  $data = $form['submitted'];

   // Insert a record into a 3rd-party module table when a submission is added.
   db_insert('mymodule_table')
     ->fields(array(
       'foo' => $data['FOO_FIELD']['#value'],
  ))
  ->execute();

}
```